# Error compiling for board Arduino Nano

Tags: arduino-ide, compilation-errors

I have multiple Arduino Nano boards.
I am able to compile or upload code only once. If I try to compile/upload again I get an error: "Error compiling for board Arduino Nano". However there is a workaround: to be able to upload again I change something in tools menu for example board or processor.
I tried all of the nanos and all of the ports.

The error message is below (verbose is enabled).

The problem appeared from nowhere.
Thank you in advance!

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\arduino-builder -dump-prefs -logger=machine -hardware C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware -tools C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\tools-builder -tools C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr -built-in-libraries C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries -libraries C:\Users\Nauris\Documents\Arduino\libraries -fqbn=arduino:avr:nano:cpu=atmega328old -vid-pid=1A86_7523 -ide-version=10812 -build-path C:\Users\Nauris\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_956544 -warnings=none -build-cache C:\Users\Nauris\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_cache_309115 -prefs=build.warn_data_percentage=75 -prefs=runtime.tools.arduinoOTA.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr -prefs=runtime.tools.arduinoOTA-1.3.0.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr -prefs=runtime.tools.avr-gcc.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr -prefs=runtime.tools.avr-gcc-7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino5.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr -prefs=runtime.tools.avrdude.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr -prefs=runtime.tools.avrdude-6.3.0-arduino17.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr -verbose C:\Users\Nauris\Documents\Arduino\RC\wifi_arduino\wifi_arduino.ino
C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\arduino-builder -compile -logger=machine -hardware C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware -tools C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\tools-builder -tools C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr -built-in-libraries C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries -libraries C:\Users\Nauris\Documents\Arduino\libraries -fqbn=arduino:avr:nano:cpu=atmega328old -vid-pid=1A86_7523 -ide-version=10812 -build-path C:\Users\Nauris\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_956544 -warnings=none -build-cache C:\Users\Nauris\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_cache_309115 -prefs=build.warn_data_percentage=75 -prefs=runtime.tools.arduinoOTA.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr -prefs=runtime.tools.arduinoOTA-1.3.0.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr -prefs=runtime.tools.avr-gcc.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr -prefs=runtime.tools.avr-gcc-7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino5.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr -prefs=runtime.tools.avrdude.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr -prefs=runtime.tools.avrdude-6.3.0-arduino17.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr -verbose C:\Users\Nauris\Documents\Arduino\RC\wifi_arduino\wifi_arduino.ino
Using board 'nano' from platform in folder: C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr
Using core 'arduino' from platform in folder: C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr
Detecting libraries used...
Error compiling for board Arduino Nano.
```

Comment: Please enable verbose output for compilation and upload in the preferences. There might be a better error description about the problem in the verbose output

Comment: If that is really the verbose output, there is something wrong with the IDE. Have you tried reinstalling it (with the latest version)? As you are on Windows, don't install the Arduino IDE from the Windows app store, since that version is buggy as hell. Use the latest version from the official website

Comment: Sorry, didn't mention that I tried to reinstall the ide. Deleted "Arduino15" folder, deleted "libraries" folder and uninstalled arduino ide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this issue by installing older arduino ide version.

Answer (score 1):

ive been having this same issue for the last 9 or so month it is driving me insane i have uninstalled and reinstalled arduino in every way i possibly can... using revouninstaller and cccleaner and even tried starting a new user account on my computer and installing it and i still have this issue.. i can only click verify or upload one time and the very next time as soon as i click it i get the exact same error message.. and not just for the nano for every board i have on the list,, it is so irritating!!!! the only work around i have found. well the simplest is to change back and forth from nano old bootloader to atmega328.. or switch back and forth from nano and uno in the boards menu..

so when im trying to put multiple codes together and get it to compile every time i click verify i have to change the board info.. or it instantly says

Using core 'arduino' from platform in folder: C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr
Detecting libraries used...
Error compiling for board Arduino Nano.

about to just throw it all in the trash